# Calling Thread must be STA

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer

I am trying to simulate a projectile and trying to create the labels in the timed event only once, because it has an object in the parameter which i need to be in the timed event. But i get this threading error when i run it. Help please!

**My Code is :**

```
    void onTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        particle newProjectile;
        newProjectile = new particle();

        bool LabelExist = false;
        if (LabelExist == false)
        {
            CreateLabels(newProjectile);
        }
    }

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(200);
        aTimer.Elapsed += onTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

    void CreateLabels(particle newProjectile)
    {
        DockPanel panelcontrol_displacement, panelcontrol_CurrentVel, panelcontrol_VerticalVel, panelcontrol_HorizontalVel, panelcontrol_Time;
        Label lbl_TimeUnits, lbl_TimeOutput, lbl_Time, lbl_DisplacementOutput, lbl_DisplacementUnits, lbl_Displacement, lbl_CurrentVel, lbl_CurrentVelOutput, lbl_HorizontalVelocityOutputs, lbl_HorizontalVelocityUnits, lbl_VerticalVelocity, lbl_HorizontalVelocity, lbl_CurrentVelUnits, lbl_VerticalVelocityOutput, lbl_VerticalVelocityUnits;
        lbl_Time = new Label();
        lbl_Time.Content = "Time";
        lbl_Time.Height = 30;
        lbl_Time.Width = 110;
        lbl_TimeOutput = new Label();
        lbl_TimeOutput.Content = "20";
        lbl_TimeOutput.Height = 30;
        lbl_TimeOutput.Width = 100;
        lbl_TimeOutput.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        lbl_TimeUnits = new Label();
        lbl_TimeUnits.Content = "s";
        lbl_CurrentVel = new Label();
        lbl_CurrentVel.Content = "Current Velocity";
        lbl_CurrentVel.Height = 30;
        lbl_CurrentVel.Width = 110;
        lbl_CurrentVelOutput = new Label();
        lbl_CurrentVelOutput.Content = "20";
        lbl_CurrentVelOutput.Height = 30;
        lbl_CurrentVelOutput.Width = 100;
        lbl_CurrentVelOutput.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        lbl_CurrentVelUnits = new Label();
        lbl_CurrentVelUnits.Content = "m/s";
        lbl_VerticalVelocity = new Label();
        lbl_VerticalVelocity.Content = "Verticle Velocity";
        lbl_VerticalVelocity.Height = 30;
        lbl_VerticalVelocity.Width = 110;
        lbl_VerticalVelocityOutput = new Label();
        lbl_VerticalVelocityOutput.Content = "20";
        lbl_VerticalVelocityOutput.Height = 30;
        lbl_VerticalVelocityOutput.Width = 100;
        lbl_VerticalVelocityOutput.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        lbl_VerticalVelocityUnits = new Label();
        lbl_VerticalVelocityUnits.Content = "m/s";
        lbl_HorizontalVelocity = new Label();
        lbl_HorizontalVelocity.Content = "Horizontal Velocity";
        lbl_HorizontalVelocity.Height = 30;
        lbl_HorizontalVelocity.Width = 110;
        lbl_HorizontalVelocityOutputs = new Label();
        lbl_HorizontalVelocityOutputs.Content = "20";
        lbl_HorizontalVelocityOutputs.Height = 30;
        lbl_HorizontalVelocityOutputs.Width = 100;
        lbl_HorizontalVelocityOutputs.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        lbl_HorizontalVelocityUnits = new Label();
        lbl_HorizontalVelocityUnits.Content = "m/s";
        lbl_Displacement = new Label();
        lbl_Displacement.Content = "Displacement";
        lbl_Displacement.Height = 30;
        lbl_Displacement.Width = 110;
        lbl_DisplacementOutput = new Label();
        lbl_DisplacementOutput.Content = "20";
        lbl_DisplacementOutput.Height = 30;
        lbl_DisplacementOutput.Width = 100;
        lbl_DisplacementOutput.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        lbl_DisplacementUnits = new Label();
        lbl_DisplacementUnits.Content = "m/s";
        panelcontrol_HorizontalVel = new DockPanel();
        panelcontrol_CurrentVel = new DockPanel();
        panelcontrol_VerticalVel = new DockPanel();
        panelcontrol_displacement = new DockPanel();
        panelcontrol_Time = new DockPanel();
        panelcontrol_CurrentVel.Children.Add(lbl_CurrentVel);
        panelcontrol_CurrentVel.Children.Add(lbl_CurrentVelOutput);
        panelcontrol_CurrentVel.Children.Add(lbl_CurrentVelUnits);
        panelcontrol_VerticalVel.Children.Add(lbl_VerticalVelocity);
        panelcontrol_VerticalVel.Children.Add(lbl_VerticalVelocityOutput);
        panelcontrol_VerticalVel.Children.Add(lbl_VerticalVelocityUnits);
        panelcontrol_HorizontalVel.Children.Add(lbl_HorizontalVelocity);
        panelcontrol_HorizontalVel.Children.Add(lbl_HorizontalVelocityOutputs);
        panelcontrol_HorizontalVel.Children.Add(lbl_HorizontalVelocityUnits);
        panelcontrol_displacement.Children.Add(lbl_Displacement);
        panelcontrol_displacement.Children.Add(lbl_DisplacementOutput);
        panelcontrol_displacement.Children.Add(lbl_DisplacementUnits);
        panelcontrol_Time.Children.Add(lbl_Time);
        panelcontrol_Time.Children.Add(lbl_TimeOutput);
        panelcontrol_Time.Children.Add(lbl_TimeUnits);
        StkPnl_Inputs.Children.Add(panelcontrol_Time);
        StkPnl_Inputs.Children.Add(panelcontrol_CurrentVel);
        StkPnl_Inputs.Children.Add(panelcontrol_VerticalVel);
        StkPnl_Inputs.Children.Add(panelcontrol_HorizontalVel);
        StkPnl_Inputs.Children.Add(panelcontrol_displacement);
        //databinding
        Binding(newProjectile, lbl_CurrentVelOutput, "CurrentVelocity");
    }
```

Comment: 99.9% of this code is irrelevant. What is missing is information about the Type of the Timer etc. It has to be deduced from `ElapsedEventArgs`

Comment: aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(200);
            aTimer.Elapsed += onTimedEvent;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            aTimer.Elapsed += onTimedEvent;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

Comment: UI code should be executed on the UI (main) Thread. Use a DispatcherTimer.

Comment: Also, your Timer will call the `onTimedEvent` twice on each tick. If that's intentional then it's an obscure (bad) way to write it.

Comment: Using the Dispatcher timer (as proposed by the one answer so far) will make the exception go away. But it's far from clear that will fix everything wrong with the code. Why are you subscribing to the timer event twice? And why do you believe it makes sense to _recreate_ and reinitialize these controls five times per second? Wouldn't it make more sense to just have the control values bound to a data structure which you update every 200ms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because it is not allowed to access UI from a background thread (the `System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed` handler is running on a background thread). This is because all the thread which handle UI in WPF should run in `Single Threaded Apartment(STA)` for synchronization purpose. And, the background workers do not run in STA.

Use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instead of a `System.Timers.Timer`.

The remark section of the MSDN page outline the difference between the 2 timers.

> If a System.Timers.Timer is used in a WPF application, it is worth noting that the System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread then the user interface (UI) thread. In order to access objects on the user interface (UI) thread, it is necessary to post the operation onto the Dispatcher of the user interface (UI) thread using Invoke or BeginInvoke.
>
> Reasons for using a DispatcherTimer opposed to a System.Timers.Timer are that the DispatcherTimer runs on the same thread as the Dispatcher and a DispatcherPriority can be set on the DispatcherTimer.

Comment: It might help others if you add the reason why this error comes.

Comment: After the edit to the question: CreateLabels is all that the Timer does. Using a Timers.Timer and then marshall all the work back is nonsense.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thought there was a good reason to use System.Timers.Timer, now it is clear a wrong timer was picked from the beginning.